# working directory changes to /tmp/ when python script runs with mlflow

Tags: python, path, mlflow

I have a strange issue with python working directory when running with mlflow run -e build .
The script running successfully locally/using IDE, but when running it with mlflow the problem is that the working directory changes to /tmp folders instead of the correct working directory where the script resides (I have some path dependencies that certain folders should be present in ./* so thats why my process fails.

I had a feeling that something with the working directory messed up so I did os.getcwd() prints and saw the issue with temp folders.

I had a similar project that I configured in a similar manner before and didn't have these issues.

any idea what might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the default behavior based on the [documentation](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/projects.html)

> By default, MLflow uses a new, temporary working directory for Git projects. This means that you should generally pass any file arguments to MLflow project using absolute, not relative, paths. If your project declares its parameters, MLflow automatically makes paths absolute for parameters of type path.

Maybe you need to specify the path through the MLproject-file but I am afraid I have not used it to give you any further help, as I had used mlflow with databricks.